# Error while deploying Django with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my django project with mod_wsgi.
My site config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName djangoproject.com
    ServerAlias www.djangoproject.com
    DocumentRoot /home/djangoproject
    ErrorLog /home/djangoproject/logs/back-error.log
    CustomLog /home/djangoproject/logs/back-access.log combined

    <Directory /home/djangoproject/djangoproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess djangoproject.com python-path=/home/djangoproject/ python-home=/home/djangoproject/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup djangoproject.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/djangoproject/djangoproject/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

But im getting error  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`

My project structure:

```
/home/djangoproject
     /djangoproject
         ...
         wsgi.py
     /venv
     /logs
     manage.py
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Update: django installed in venv
`(venv) root@nik:/home/djangoproject# pip show django
Name: Django
Version: 4.1.7`

Comment: Update: i found same posts, but answers are not working for me:(

Comment: Your configuration seems correct. The only thing maybe is the ending slash for your daemon process. I would rather set the following "python-path=/home/djangoproject python-home=/home/djangoproject/venv/"